# Mongoid::Criteria to array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a `Mongoid::Criteria` object `data` which has 634 results:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
selector: {"search_id"=>155, "posted_time"=>{"$gte"=>2016-05-31 15:43:40 UTC, "$lte"=>2016-06-07 15:43:40 UTC}}
options:  {:sort=>{"posted_time"=>-1}, :limit=>200}
class:    MongoPost
embedded: false>

data.count
=> 634

data.to_a.count
=> 200
```

This is a problem, because when I map the object, the result is not which I expected:

```
data.map{|element| element.type}.count
=> 200
```

What is doing on, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You have a `limit` there, see?

Comment: yes, can I modify it?

Comment: yeah, one possibility is to not set the limit in the first place.

Comment: ok, I see, but why the object `count` returns all elements that match with previous `where`criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your criteria has `limit: 200` on it. `each` (and, by extension, `map`) respects the limit. That's why you get 200 records.

Why `count` ignores limit - this is a good question. I don't know exactly, but I suspect it has something to do with pagination. That is, having one criteria object, you can fetch a page **and** know total number of matching records (from which you can infer total number of pages).

To get count of limited query you can do something like:

```
criteria.lazy.count
```

This `count` is not the one from Mongoid, it's from Enumerable and will respect the limit.

About unsetting the limit: quick googling didn't reveal a suitable api, but you can always override limit with a bigger value. This, perhaps:

```
criteria.limit(criteria.count).to_a # get all records, without limit
```

#### Note about efficiency

Don't be fooled by the `lazy` keyword. It's only there to turn the mongo relation into an enumerable. There's nothing lazy about that. It still runs the query and iterates the result set. Essentially, it's the same as

```
criteria.to_a.count
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of mongoid (5.x), this is possible via options to `.count` method.

```
criteria.count(limit: 10)
```

Or, to reuse whatever limit is already set on the criteria

```
criteria.count(criteria.options.slice(:limit))
```